# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map' . How to resolve this error?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, generative-adversarial-network

```
train_horses = train_horses.map(
    preprocess_image_train, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).cache().shuffle(
    BUFFER_SIZE).batch(1)

train_zebras = train_zebras.map(
    preprocess_image_train, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).cache().shuffle(
    BUFFER_SIZE).batch(1)

test_horses = test_horses.map(
    preprocess_image_test, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).cache().shuffle(
    BUFFER_SIZE).batch(1)

test_zebras = test_zebras.map(
    preprocess_image_test, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).cache().shuffle(
    BUFFER_SIZE).batch(1)
```

What is the error in this code,it is showing attribute error and i am not able to resolve it.

**THE ERROR IS**:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-00c14af042b9> in <module>()
----> 1 train_horses = train_horses.map(
      2     preprocess_image_train, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).cache().shuffle(
      3     BUFFER_SIZE).batch(1)
      4 
      5 train_zebras = train_zebras.map(
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'map'

**LINK TO COLAB**:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rlgjFnhPGJTjUv368imG9q1VEGQZ0N13?usp=sharing

Comment: `map()` isn't a list method, it's a regular function. And you need to pass a function to call. `map(train_horses, lambda horse: ...)`

Comment: Based on the other arguments to `map`, it seems you don't expect `train_horses` et al to be lists, but some other type that *does* have a `map` method with a particular signature.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `train_horses.map(`, what do you expect `train_horses` to be? What do you expect the `.map` part to mean? Why should it be possible to write that code? For example, did you see something in the documentation about it? If so, you should check that again more carefully, and then also verify your assumptions about the code. See also https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is exactly correct.  Lists do not have a `map` attribute.  There are two possibilities.  Either `train_horses` was supposed to be a different type (`numpy` array, maybe?) or you meant to use the standalone map function:

```
test_horses = map( test_horses, 
    preprocess_image_train, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).cache().shuffle(
    BUFFER_SIZE).batch(1)
```

The fact that you are trying to call `cache`, `shuffle` and `batch` on the output of this strongly suggests that the problem is the former, because `map` results don't have those attributes.  `test_horses` was supposed to be some other kind of object.  You didn't show us how you created it, so we can't provide much more help.

#### Followup

`num_parallel_calls` is a TensorFlow tensor attribute.  So, apparently you intended to turn `test_horses` into a tensor, but you forgot to do that.

Comment: `num_parallel_calls` is not a valid option to `map()`

Comment: Good clue -- you gave me something to Google.